# Can I somehow pause all processes of an user logged in in background?

Tags: login, users, lock-screen, process, cpu-load

I have mainly two accounts on my 14.10 laptop: Mine (admin) and my brother's (restricted).

Now when my brother is logged in and runs some applications like firefox with flash player, it consumes much CPU. I have an Intel 2GHz, 2 cores, but with software rendering because of half-broken graphics card.
When he now locks his account and I log into mine, CPU is at about 80% even if I do nothing. `indicator-multiload` shows firefox and compiz of the other user as most consuming processes, sometimes xorg too, I think.

So in a nutshell: Can I run a command/script to pause the processes started by another user and resume them again after I have done my work? Would be nice if that could be executed at every locking/login/logout.

But is this safe for all applications? Where do I have to pay attention?

Comment: Try `pkill -STOP -u brother`.

Comment: @muru But doesn't this kill the processes? I want that he is able to continue whatever he was doing when he logs back in. How do I pause and resume processes? And does this automatically work on all of his processes or is there more scripting needed? And is it safe or might some apps crash and lead to data loss or kill the whole system?

Comment: A similar question on U&L: [how-can-i-pause-resume-rsync](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5959/how-can-i-pause-resume-rsync), but I am not really sure how to apply this to my own problem.

Comment: To apply *that*, you do `pkill -STOP -u brother`, or `pkill -u TSTP -u brother`, if you're feeling polite. You could refine a bit, say specifying firefox or Xorg, if you feel like it..

Comment: @muru And if I only give the -u parameter, it works on all processes of that user? But is this really safe or might some apps crash (especially those accessing files or things like compiz and xorg)?

Comment: Only one way to find out. I haven't ever mass-stopped a user's set of processes, so no idea how this will end up.

Comment: And how will I resume the processes? Do they continue automatically when he logs back in/unlocks his account?

Comment: Doubt that will happen. The opposite of `TSTP`/`STOP` is `CONT`, so `pkill -CONT -u brother`.

Comment: @muru: Thank you, it worked (with `-STOP`)! And everything still runs when I resume the processes and log into my brother's account. Only problem is that I should find a way to automatically resume the processes (or execute a script to do so) when I log into that locked account. Otherwise I get an unresponsive black screen and somehow get back to the login screen. Please convert your comments to an answer and add a solution for the "auto-resurrection" if possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way would be to send the `SIGSTOP` signal to all of your brother's processes:

```
sudo pkill -STOP -u brother
```

To awaken the stopped processes, the `SIGCONT` signal is used:

```
sudo pkill -CONT -u brother
```

---

You can use an Upstart session job, one which would run when you logged in or out or locked or unlocked your screen. For example, create a `.conf` file in `~/.config/upstart` (say `~/.config/upstart/stop-brother.conf`) containing:

```
description "Stop all my brother's processes"
start on desktop-start or desktop-unlock
task

exec sudo pkill -STOP -u brother
```

And a converse file (say `~/.config/upstart/start-brother.conf`) containing:

```
description "Resume all my brother's processes"
start on desktop-end or desktop-lock
task

exec sudo pkill -CONT -u brother
```

You also need a `NOPASSWD` entry in `sudoers`:

```
sudo tee /etc/sudoers.d/stop-brother <<EOF
$USER ALL = (ALL) /usr/bin/pkill -STOP -u brother, /usr/bin/pkill -CONT -u brother
EOF
```

Now the signals should be sent automatically when you log in, log out, lock or unlock the screen. You can manually initiate either using:

```
start stop-brother
start start-brother
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21306/discussion-on-answer-by-muru-can-i-somehow-pause-all-processes-of-an-user-logged).

Comment: @RolandiXor We (= @Fabby) already have opened a chat room for this question. It is called "Sleep, brother sleep". Could you merge those two, please?

Comment: Sure! Next time, please flag the question before the system kicks in to flag it ;)

Answer (score 2):

Check which application is taking higher resources.

Find the pid of that application using the command

`pidof "application name"` without the quotes.

```
 sudo kill -STOP "ID of the process"
```

Then once you have completed your work use the below command to start that stopped process.

```
sudo kill -CONT "PID that you have killed earlier"
```

Give it a try!

Comment: Thanks! It works, but I prefer @muru's solution, because it is only one command for all processes. So upvoted, but not accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Check this [Save and Restore Linux Processes with CRIU](http://www.admin-magazine.com/Archive/2014/22/Save-and-Restore-Linux-Processes-with-CRIU?utm_source=ADMIN%20Newsletter&utm_campaign=ADMIN_Update_80_Google_Compute_Engine_2014-09-30&utm_medium=email)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it would be nice if you could improve it by adding a summary of the article you linked. Because sometimes links become dead and then your answer loses its sense. Also the people who are having this problem must follow the link and switch tabs and read through a long article. So please [improve your answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer) and you will also get some upvotes. Thanks :-D