# Running a bash script on "Switch User"?

Tags: bash, users, events, switch-user

I've had my first dabble with bash and got a working script going for each user on session start which checks if a NAS share is mounted and if it is unmounts it and mounts as the current user. This works great but now I have a problem, on the first "Switch User" the script is executed as the session for the new user starts. Switching back however the drive is mounted as the previous user, running the script works so it appears that what works for the session start (.config/autostart) doesn't handle this user switching and I guess that makes sense.

Question is, how to run my little script again when a session restarts for each user after a "Switch User" happens?

Comment: Please explain `on the first "Switch User" the script is executed as the session for the new user starts. Switching back however the drive is mounted as the previous user, running the script works` a more broadly/clearly. Also add your script to [the question](http://askubuntu.com/posts/607753/edit).

Comment: This sounds unnecessarily complicated. Can you not mount it rw for everybody?

Comment: @heemayl Ok, So, I log in as user A, my .config/autostart shizzle runs and the NAS is mounted as User A.

Then I switch to user B, again, .config/autostart for that user runs the script and the NAS is mounted as user B.

Then I SWITCH BACK to user A, and the script IS NOT EXECUTED, the NAS is still mounted as user B.

My script itself is irrelevent, I'm asking where to put a script or how to call a script when a "switch user" event happens. That clearer?

Comment: @glenn jackman, ahah, yeah I could, but this NAS has a cool feature in that it gives a home directory to all users, other parts of it I mount for everyone. but Home is unique to different users so I'd like to just mount "NAS Home" for everyone based on who they are...

Comment: Sounds like you need a separate mount point for each user. You have to handle multiple users logged in somehow.

Comment: @glenn jackman hmm I see what you mean, but I'd still have the switch user problem, unless I abandon the idea of automatically mounting the drive altogether. which would be a pain as I'd like to automate things which would require it to be mounted

Comment: You can still "automount", but each user has his own mountpoint. Then it doesn't matter if you switch users because A and B no longer clash. Unless your tools hardcode a single mountpoint, in which case you're screwed.

Comment: I would be interested in how to run a script whenever the logged in user switches anyway. It's part of my Q there: http://askubuntu.com/questions/587096/can-i-somehow-pause-all-processes-of-an-user-logged-in-in-background

Comment: @glennjackman ok I'll have a play with that, but won't user A see user B's NAS home in their nautilus after  couple of switches? Like I said I'll experiment a bit and see for myself, thanks for your time :)

Comment: Through which protocol does your NAS expose its data? NFS and CIFS (with extensions) support Unix-style permissions, so one mount point for all users may be enough, if the permissions of the underlying file system are set correctly. No re-mounting for every user necessary.

Comment: @glennjackman has the solution to mounting the NAS for differnet users, so thanks for that. Different mount points in each users Home took care of that. Still no answers to the run a script when a user gets switched though.